# Is reliance on $this counterintuitive to test driven development in PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, scope, tdd

I am attempting to make my PHP code more easily testable. Here is a scenario. I have a `client` object. The `client` object has properties that all correspond to fields in a database table. In order to more completely describe the `client` object, I'd like to add a method called `licensees()` to my `client` object model.

In the past, I might have made this a static method within my client model...something like this:

```
public static function licensees($id)
{
    $licensees = static::query()
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->related('categories', array('where' => array(array('group', '=', 30))))
        ->get();

    return $licensees;
}
```

There are implications to this method that I don't like, not the least of which is that you can pass in any `$id` and get the result, regardless of whether of not the `$id` is within the scope of the `client` privileges or not.

To me, a safer method would be to implement a non-static method that takes into account the scope of the `client` object:

```
public function licensees()
{
    $licensees = $this->query()
        ->where('id', $this->id)
        ->related('categories', array('where' => array(array('group', '=', 30))))
        ->get();

    return $licensees;
}
```

I *think* that this is a better solution in terms of usability and security, but I don't really see how it is any more testable than the static method. In fact, it looks **less** testable to me because of the [singleton implication](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/) of using `$this`. I've been reading a lot lately about [test driven development](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/the-newbies-guide-to-test-driven-development/) and using dependency injection as a form of inversion of control, and I'm trying to implement it:

```
public function licensees(Client $client)
{
    $licensees = $client->query()
        ->where('id', $client->id)
        ->related('categories', array('where' => array(array('group', '=', 30))))
        ->get();

    return $licensees;
}
```

To me this actually looks testable, because it will allow me to easily send in a `mockClient` instead of a real client when running tests. Am I understanding this concept correctly?

It seems a bit redundant to pass in the `$client` object to the `model` in this case, because the `model` itself has `$this` context. However, I believe that reliance on `$this` for context in an object model is an inhibitor to testability. Is that a valid statement, or am I off base here?

Comment: If it's public method, you can test it and there's no reason to send the object of itself into it, it's already there as `$this`. Just test the class as a whole, I think might be overdoing it a bit, if you're making a mock of a class you're currently testing. That doesn't make sense to me. But who am I to say, when I'm so definitely underdoing it?

Comment: Or I'm pretty sure you can mock just some methods of the class, so just mock what you need to mock, then the mocked object should keep the original `licensees` function which you can test on the mocked object itself. For example, mock just the `get` method and set checking of expected results in it. It should work that way, although I'm not 100% sure.